# pROC test difference from AUC = 0.5

Tags: proc-r-package

I would like to know how can I use pROC package to test whether a given AUC value is statistically significantly different from an AUC = 0.5. I can get confidence intervals but I would also like to report the associated p-values.

Thank you in advance for you time and help!

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that directly with pROC, but you don't need to. Once you realize that [asking whether the curve = 0.5 is actually equivalent to asking whether the median values of your two classes are equal](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/75050/in-r-how-to-compute-the-p-value-for-area-under-roc/83972#83972), you can easily perform a [Wilcoxon Rank Sum Tests](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/topics/wilcox.test):

```
wilcox.test(cases, controls)
```